# Automatically import CSV in Prestashop

Tags: php, csv, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to automatically import .CSV file into Prestashop.

The imports must be made at a certain period of time between two consecutive imports. I know there is a CSV Import under the ***Advanced Parameters*** tab.

I failed to imagine a reliable algorithm to get the job done. I must mention that I'm new to Prestashop.
So, any suggestion/documentation is welcomed!
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=prestashop+import+cron+job

Comment: Asking for off-site documentation is off-topic for SO.